# File name issue with YUI Compressor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, msbuild, yui-compressor

I am using YUICompressor MSBuild task in my .Net project. I want the compressed files to named as file_name.min.js and file_name.min.css. I am using the below compressor task in my buildconfig.xml:

```
<CssCompressorTask
      SourceFiles="@(CssFiles)"
      DeleteSourceFiles="false"
      OutputFile="%(CssFiles.Identity)"
      CompressionType="Standard"
      LoggingType="Info"
      PreserveComments="false"
      LineBreakPosition="-1"
  />
```

I am getting the minified file as file_name.css.min.css, but I want it to be file_name.min.css
Can someone please guide me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use %(CssFiles.Filename) instead of %(CssFiles.Identity).
See [MSBuild item metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)